# Performance degradation in salesforce sandbox - batches and asynchronous are taking too long time

Tags: batch, future, schedulebatch, performance

We are running start of day and end of day jobs before and after the business hours, but from around 4 days we are observing even without any data sets the batches are taking too long to run. Previously all batches used to run in 5-10 min, but now they are going till 8-10 hours and most of them are going to Queued state.

For testing we tried to run an future method without any code, this is also going to queued state and taking around 5-10 minutes to finish execution.

Tried reaching salesforce support, but haven't got much help from them as for our licence type there is no support for development things.

We are planning to move the solution to production, but we are not sure whether the same delay may be observed in production too.

Is this common in sandboxes or do we have any workaround to come out of this?

Comment: did you check status.salesforce.com.  In previous few days there is lots of thing going on there.

Comment: @TusharSharma thank you,yes i have checked where the instance health is showing cs15 is good and available.

Comment: If you haven't already, read [Asynchronous Processing in Force com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Asynchronous_Processing_in_Force_com). Is your code doing something quite simple and consistent with the "Best Practices" in the linked page? Unfortunately Salesforce make no guarantees about time limits on asynchronous processing. If you are lucky, your problem is a short term overloading of the instance you are running on.

Comment: @KeithC Yes you are correct seems to be it's a short term problem , just now i have cross checked the instance is running normally with very minimal time.